# Is it safe to poll for a variable written by other threads in a C program?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, compiler-optimization

Consider the following snippet of C code:

```
int flag = 0;
/* Assume that the functions lock_helper, unlock_helper implement enter/leave in
 * a global mutex and thread_start_helper simply runs the function in separate
 * operating-system threads */

void worker1()
{
  /* Long-running job here */
  lock_helper();
  if (!flag)
    flag = 1;
  unlock_helper();
}

void worker2()
{
  /* Another long-running job here */
  lock_helper();
  if (!flag)
    flag = 2;
  unlock_helper();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  thread_start_helper(&worker1);
  thread_start_helper(&worker2);
  do
  {
    /* doing something */
  } while (!flag);
  /* do something with 'flag' */
}
```

Questions:

- Is it it possible that 'flag' will always be 0 for the main thread(and it
  becomes stuck in the do/while loop) due to some compiler optimization?
- Will the 'volatile' modifier make any difference?
- If the answer is 'depends on a feature provided by the compiler', is there any
  way I can check for this 'feature' with a configuration script at
  compile-time?

Comment: did you call **join function to wait for the thread for worker1 & worker2 . I would say flag would be either 1 or 2 in this program

Comment: (1) Yes, it can. (2) The loop wouldn't become stuck, but you may get invalid results because of a race condition (e.g. flag of 1 may be replaced with 2, and vice verse) (3) This is a combination of hardware optimization and a compiler optimization - hardware can get your loop stuck even without your compiler's help (because of CPU cache). I doubt that a script-based check would help.

Comment: Theres no race condition for writing the variable, see the lock/unlock helpers around it

Comment: I wouldn't rely on a value read from a variable which might have been in the process of modification while I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can assume that the loading of an aligned `int` is an atomic operation, the only danger with your code is the optimizer: your compiler is allowed to optimize away all but the first reads of `flag` within `main()`, i. e. to convert your code into

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  thread_start_helper(&worker1);
  thread_start_helper(&worker2);
  /* doing something */
  if(!flag) {
      while(1) /* doing something */
  }
  //This point is unreachable and the following can be optimized away entirely.
  /* do something with 'flag' */
}
```

There are two ways you can make sure that this does not happen: 1. make `flag` volatile, which is a bad idea because it includes quite a bit of *unwanted* overhead, and 2. introduce the necessary memory barriers. Due to the atomicity of reading an `int` and the fact that you only want to interprete the value of `flag` after it has changed, you should be able to get away with just a compiler barrier before the loop condition like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  thread_start_helper(&worker1);
  thread_start_helper(&worker2);
  do
  {
    /* doing something */
    barrier();
  } while(!flag)
  /* do something with 'flag' */
}
```

The `barrier()` used here is very lightweight, it is the cheapest of all barriers available.

This is not enough if you want to analyze any other data that is written before `flag` is raised, because you might still load stale data from memory (because the CPU decided to prefetch the value). For a comprehensive discussion of memory fences, their necessity, and their use, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Finally, you should be aware, that the other writer thread may modify `flag` at any time after the `do{}while()` loop exits. So, you should immediately copy its value to a shadow variable like this:

```
int myFlagCopy;
do
{
  /* doing something */
  barrier();
} while(!(myFlagCopy = flag))
/* do something with 'myFlagCopy' */
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is likely to work as is, but is somewhat fragile. For one thing, it depends on the reads and writes to `flag` being atomic on the processor being used (and that `flag`'s alignment is sufficient).

I would recommend either using a read lock to read the value of `flag` or use functionality of whatever threading library you are using to make `flag` properly atomic.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the while is executed before the threads... you have to wait the execution of thread before, using pthread_join()

Comment: That is no danger, `flag` would be zero in that case, and the behaviour would be exactly as the OP desires.